# Regarding creating multiple servers from SQL Azure portal

Tags: azure-sql-database

recently an awesome SQL Azure may 2011 update was realeased which allowed us to provision multiple servers under a single subscription. 
I am able to create multiple servers through the new Azure portal but can we do the same from the sql azure portal (SQL.Azure.com)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL.azure.com](http://sql.azure.com) is the old, non-Silverlight portal, and you won't find new features such as multiple-server administration. You should be accessing all SQL Azure database administration from the new portal at [windows.azure.com](http://windows.azure.com).

You'll find that the same holds true for [appfabric.azure.com](http://appfabric.azure.com), which is all-but-abandoned at this point.

Comment: Thanks David - i have played with new portal and it's amazing! Thanks for the answer!